# Prevent Chrome from knowing that window/tab is switched

Tags: google-chrome, website, alt-tab

How can I completely fool a website into thinking that I haven't minimized the browser window or opened and switched to a new tab?

There is a website which detects and terminates the session after a  few warnings if I minimize the browser or open and switch to a new tab.  How can I fool this site? The site does not allow access using Firefox, it only allows Google Chrome. I'm using Manjaro Linux with kde(xorg).

Comment: Run it in a virtual machine?

Comment: I need it for my exams

Answer (score 0):

should work (i apologize for some messy code, this is some example code for content2.js):

```
console.log("v3");

function fakeAddEventListener(type, listener, options) {
  console.log("addEventListener called for:", type);

  if (!this.lastListenerInfo) {
    this.lastListenerInfo = [];
  }

  if (type !== 'visibilitychange') {
    const listenerInfo = { type, listener, options };
    this.lastListenerInfo.push(listenerInfo);
    this.realAddEventListener(type, listener, options);
  } else {
    console.log(type, "detected");
    removeVisibilityChangeListeners();
  }
}

function removeVisibilityChangeListeners() {
  const arr = window.lastListenerInfo;

  for (const event of arr) {
    if (event.type === 'visibilitychange') {
      window.realRemoveEventListener(event.type, event.listener, event.options || false);
      document.realRemoveEventListener(event.type, event.listener, event.options || false);
      window.lastListenerInfo.splice(window.lastListenerInfo.indexOf(event), 1);
      console.log(`removed event listener for ${event.type}`);
    }
  }
}

function setup() {
  setInterval(removeVisibilityChangeListeners, 1000);
}

Document.prototype.realAddEventListener = Document.prototype.addEventListener;
Document.prototype.addEventListener = fakeAddEventListener;
Document.prototype.realRemoveEventListener = Document.prototype.removeEventListener;

Window.prototype.realAddEventListener = Window.prototype.addEventListener;
Window.prototype.addEventListener = fakeAddEventListener;
Window.prototype.realRemoveEventListener = Window.prototype.removeEventListener;

setup();
```

you can use it in a chrome extension

heres an example manifest.json file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Remove Visibility Change Listeners",
    "version": "0",
    "description": "Removes all visibility change event listeners on a specific site",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*.example.com/*"],  
        "world": "MAIN",
        "js": ["content2.js"],
        "all_frames": false,
        "run_at":"document_start"
      }
    ],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
  }
```